# gwt-maven-plugin: Compile fails "with status 1"

Tags: maven, gwt, dependencies, command-line-arguments, gwt-maven-plugin

I've been working on a GWT project for a while, and I believe since I've added new dependencies, I get the error below.

> Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:gwt-maven-plugin:2.6.1:compile (default) on project project: Command [[
>
> /bin/sh -c /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386/jre/bin/java -Xmx512m -classpath /home/user/git/project/target/project-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/WEB-INF/classes:/home/user/.m2/repository/A.jar:/home/user/.m2/repository/B.jar:... **a lot more dependencies** ... com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler -logLevel INFO -style OBF -war /home/user/git/project/target/project-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT -localWorkers 1 -XfragmentCount -1 -sourceLevel 1.6 -gen /home/user/git/project/target/.generated my.project.Project

1. When I run the command given in the error on Windows 7 I get "The input is too long".
2. When I run the command on Ubuntu, no errors shown. `echo $?` however shows the returned status of 1.

The stacktrace given by `mvn package -X` looks like

> at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:217)
>       at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
>       at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
>       at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
>       at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
>       at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
>       at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
>       at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
>       at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
>       at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
>       at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
>       at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
>       at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
>       at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
>       at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
>       at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
>
> Caused by: org.codehaus.mojo.gwt.shell.ForkedProcessExecutionException: Command [[
>   /bin/sh -c /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386/jre/bin/java -Xmx512m -classpath /home/user/git/project/target/project-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/WEB-INF/classes:/home/user/.m2/repository/A.jar:/home/user/.m2/repository/B.jar:... **a lot more dependencies** ... com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler -logLevel INFO -style OBF -war /home/user/git/project/target/project-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT -localWorkers 1 -XfragmentCount -1 -sourceLevel 1.6 -gen /home/user/git/project/target/.generated my.project.Project
>   ]] failed with status 1
>       at org.codehaus.mojo.gwt.shell.AbstractGwtShellMojo$JavaCommand.execute(AbstractGwtShellMojo.java:485)
>       at org.codehaus.mojo.gwt.shell.CompileMojo.compile(CompileMojo.java:446)
>       at org.codehaus.mojo.gwt.shell.CompileMojo.doExecute(CompileMojo.java:351)
>       at org.codehaus.mojo.gwt.shell.AbstractGwtShellMojo.execute(AbstractGwtShellMojo.java:172)
>       at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
>       at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
>       ... 19 more

The `mvn package` output looks like

```
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building project 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.5:resources (default-resources) @ project ---
[debug] execute contextualize
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 6 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) @ project ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-war-plugin:2.1.1:exploded (default) @ project ---
[INFO] Exploding webapp
[INFO] Assembling webapp [project] in [/home/user/git/project/target/project-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
[INFO] Processing war project
[INFO] Copying webapp resources [/home/user/git/project/src/main/webapp]
[INFO] Webapp assembled in [475 msecs]
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.5:testResources (default-testResources) @ project ---
[debug] execute contextualize
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 2 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ project ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.10:test (default-test) @ project ---
[INFO] Surefire report directory: /home/user/git/project/target/surefire-reports

-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------

Results :

Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

[INFO] 
[INFO] --- gwt-maven-plugin:2.6.0:compile (default) @ project ---
[INFO] auto discovered modules [my.module.Module, my.project.Project]
[INFO] my.module.Module has no EntryPoint - compilation skipped
[INFO] Compiling module my.project.Project
[INFO]    Validating units:
[INFO]       Ignored 115 units with compilation errors in first pass.
[INFO] Compile with -strict or with -logLevel set to TRACE or DEBUG to see all errors.
[INFO]    Computing all possible rebind results for 'com.google.gwt.useragent.client.UserAgentAsserter'
[INFO]       Rebinding com.google.gwt.useragent.client.UserAgentAsserter
[INFO]          Checking rule <generate-with class='com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.gwt.rebind.RequestFactoryGenerator'/>
[INFO]             [WARN] Unknown type 'com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.shared.RequestFactory' specified in deferred binding rule
[INFO]          Checking rule <generate-with class='com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.gwt.rebind.RequestFactoryEditorDriverGenerator'/>
[INFO]             [WARN] Unknown type 'com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.gwt.client.RequestFactoryEditorDriver' specified in deferred binding rule
[INFO]          Checking rule <generate-with class='com.google.gwt.editor.rebind.SimpleBeanEditorDriverGenerator'/>
[INFO]             [WARN] Detected warnings related to 'com.google.gwt.editor.client.SimpleBeanEditorDriver'.   Are validation-api-<version>.jar and validation-api-<version>-sources.jar on the classpath?
[INFO]             Specify -logLevel DEBUG to see all errors.
[INFO]             [WARN] Unknown type 'com.google.gwt.editor.client.SimpleBeanEditorDriver' specified in deferred binding rule
[INFO]       Rebinding com.google.gwt.useragent.client.UserAgentAsserter
[INFO]          Checking rule <generate-with class='com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.gwt.rebind.RequestFactoryGenerator'/>
[INFO]             [WARN] Unknown type 'com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.shared.RequestFactory' specified in deferred binding rule
[INFO]          Checking rule <generate-with class='com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.gwt.rebind.RequestFactoryEditorDriverGenerator'/>
[INFO]             [WARN] Unknown type 'com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.gwt.client.RequestFactoryEditorDriver' specified in deferred binding rule
[INFO]       Rebinding com.google.gwt.useragent.client.UserAgentAsserter
[INFO]          Checking rule <generate-with class='com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.gwt.rebind.RequestFactoryGenerator'/>
[INFO]             [WARN] Unknown type 'com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.shared.RequestFactory' specified in deferred binding rule
[INFO]          Checking rule <generate-with class='com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.gwt.rebind.RequestFactoryEditorDriverGenerator'/>
[INFO]             [WARN] Unknown type 'com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.gwt.client.RequestFactoryEditorDriver' specified in deferred binding rule

... Lots of Rebinding similar to above...

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 30.074s
[INFO] Finished at: Tue Jun 03 09:18:19 MST 2014
[INFO] Final Memory: 17M/436M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:gwt-maven-plugin:2.6.0:compile (default) on project project: Command [[
[ERROR] /usr/bin/java -Xmx512m -classpath *long classpath* com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler -logLevel INFO -style OBF -war /home/user/git/project/target/project-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT -localWorkers 8 -XfragmentCount -1 -sourceLevel 1.6 -gen /home/user/git/project/target/.generated my.project.Project
[ERROR] ]] failed with status 1
```

Comment: Is there really no output from the GWT compiler earlier in the output/log? (generally before the summary of modules that successfully built or failed)

Comment: I updated with the output shown in the eclispe console by running `mvn package`. Does that help? I was also mistaken: On ubuntu the command also returns 1, even though I didn't find obvious errors in the output of it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I ran mvn package -X and found the following errors

`[INFO]    [ERROR] Errors in 'gwtupload/client/DecoratedFileUpload.java'
[INFO]       [ERROR] Line 371: Rebind result 'gwtupload.client.DecoratedFileUpload.DecoratedFileUploadImpl' cannot be abstract`

So I updated the dependency `gwtupload` to a newer version which resolved my problem.

The reason I had ignored this error in a previous attempt, was that `mvn package` was successful before, using this dependency in this specific version. So I thought this error must have always been there, still leading to a successful package.

Comment: Thanks for the Debug flag suggestion with maven, we were stuck with similar gwt error , its a shame that the final exception does not has the correct errors

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar issue when MVN building a Vaadin project in Cygwyn 32-bit version. But when I switched to Cygwyn 64-bit this issue is resolved.

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.vaadin:vaadin-maven-plugin:7.7.2:compile (default) on project vaadin-app: Command [[
...
[ERROR] ]] failed with status 1
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
...
failed with status 1
        at org.codehaus.mojo.gwt.shell.CompileMojo.compile(CompileMojo.java:582)
        at org.codehaus.mojo.gwt.shell.CompileMojo.doExecute(CompileMojo.java:435)
        at org.codehaus.mojo.gwt.shell.AbstractGwtShellMojo.execute(AbstractGwtShellMojo.java:182)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
```