# Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:gwt-maven-plugin:2.8.0:compile

Tags: java, maven, gwt, command-line-arguments, gwt-maven-plugin

I am migrating my gwt from 2.6 to 2.8 
I tried running mvn clean install and getting the below error while executing the below plugin. I am using gwt-maven-plugin to build the gwt code and running into the below issue. There is no clue whats wrong with the maven failure

found a similar question but the answers dont fit my scenario.
[gwt-maven-plugin: Compile fails "with status 1"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24002029/gwt-maven-plugin-compile-fails-with-status-1)

```
[INFO]          Rule did not match
[INFO]          Found better fallback match for <replace-with class='com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.StackTraceCreator.CollectorEmulated'/>
[INFO]          Rebind result was com.google.gwt.animation.client.AnimationScheduler.AnimationSupportDetector
[INFO] Closing cache file: C:\Jesline\gwtApp-Code\MigrationWorkSpace\gwtAppWeb\target\gwt-unitCache\gwt-unitCache-f160a61272c5ebe805cd2d3d3256ed3ecf14893f-0000015DBE69F624 (0 units written)
[INFO] Deleting empty file: C:\Jesline\gwtApp-Code\MigrationWorkSpace\gwtAppWeb\target\gwt-unitCache\gwt-unitCache-f160a61272c5ebe805cd2d3d3256ed3ecf14893f-0000015DBE69F624
[INFO] Shutting down PersistentUnitCache thread
[INFO] Shutting down PersistentUnitCache thread
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 03:10 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-08-07T15:37:54-05:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 43M/386M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:gwt-maven-plugin:2.8.0:compile (default) on project gwtAppWeb: Command [[
[ERROR] cmd.exe /X /C "C:\Jesline\Software\Java8\jdk1.8.0_101\jre\bin\java -Xmx2048M -Xms1024M com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler -logLevel DEBUG -war C:\Jesline\gwtApp-Code\MigrationWorkSpace\gwtAppWeb\target\gwtAppWeb-3.0.0-SNAPSHOT -localWorkers 4 -draftCompile -XfragmentCount -1 -sourceLevel auto -gen C:\Jesline\gwtApp-Code\MigrationWorkSpace\gwtAppWeb\target\.generated com.poc.gwtApp.web.SEWeb"
[ERROR] ]] failed with status 1
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:gwt-maven-plugin:2.8.0:compile (default) on project gwtAppWeb: Command [[
cmd.exe /X /C "C:\Jesline\Software\Java8\jdk1.8.0_101\jre\bin\java -Xmx2048M -Xms1024M com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler -logLevel DEBUG -war C:\Jesline\gwtApp-Code\MigrationWorkSpace\gwtAppWeb\target\gwtAppWeb-3.0.0-SNAPSHOT -localWorkers 4 -draftCompile -XfragmentCount -1 -sourceLevel auto -gen C:\Jesline\gwtApp-Code\MigrationWorkSpace\gwtAppWeb\target\.generated com.poc.gwtApp.web.SEWeb"
]] failed with status 1
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:212)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Command [[
cmd.exe /X /C "C:\Jesline\Software\Java8\jdk1.8.0_101\jre\bin\java -Xmx2048M -Xms1024M com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler -logLevel DEBUG -war C:\Jesline\gwtApp-Code\MigrationWorkSpace\gwtAppWeb\target\gwtAppWeb-3.0.0-SNAPSHOT -localWorkers 4 -draftCompile -XfragmentCount -1 -sourceLevel auto -gen C:\Jesline\gwtApp-Code\MigrationWorkSpace\gwtAppWeb\target\.generated com.poc.gwtApp.web.SEWeb"
]] failed with status 1
    at org.codehaus.mojo.gwt.shell.CompileMojo.compile(CompileMojo.java:520)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.gwt.shell.CompileMojo.doExecute(CompileMojo.java:387)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.gwt.shell.AbstractGwtShellMojo.execute(AbstractGwtShellMojo.java:162)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:207)
    ... 20 more
Caused by: org.codehaus.mojo.gwt.shell.JavaCommandException: Command [[
cmd.exe /X /C "C:\Jesline\Software\Java8\jdk1.8.0_101\jre\bin\java -Xmx2048M -Xms1024M com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler -logLevel DEBUG -war C:\Jesline\gwtApp-Code\MigrationWorkSpace\gwtAppWeb\target\gwtAppWeb-3.0.0-SNAPSHOT -localWorkers 4 -draftCompile -XfragmentCount -1 -sourceLevel auto -gen C:\Jesline\gwtApp-Code\MigrationWorkSpace\gwtAppWeb\target\.generated com.poc.gwtApp.web.SEWeb"
]] failed with status 1
    at org.codehaus.mojo.gwt.shell.JavaCommand.execute(JavaCommand.java:330)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.gwt.shell.CompileMojo.compile(CompileMojo.java:516)
    ... 24 more
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

Below is my Maven Plugin configuraion

```
<plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>gwt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.0</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>compile</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <!-- <module>com.citi.sevi.web</module> -->
          <logLevel>DEBUG</logLevel>
          <runTarget>${tomcat.context}/SEWeb</runTarget>
          <noServer>true</noServer>
          <draftCompile>true</draftCompile>
          <extraJvmArgs>-Xmx2048M -Xms1024M</extraJvmArgs>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>`
```

Comment: Probably some compilation error, add 'mvn -X' and <failOnError>true</failOnError> and show the whole log.

Comment: check your java version where you are running the application, you can try  `jdk 8` with `gwt 2.8`.

Comment: And @mayank Yes i am using Jdk 8 and gwt 2.8.0. Infact, i used jdk8 hance i have to upgrade my gwt from 2.5 to 2.8.

Comment: @IgnacioBaca : I have run the code using -X but still no clue.

Comment: please, add the whole log! hehe the error is in the gwt compilation phase.